# Node API fill database with excel using it's own controller?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a node/express API that get all days a .xlsx files with a lot of data (with node-schedule and sftp)
I use XLSX for read datas in this excel file, and the next step is to fill the database with it.
But, the problem is that excel file have multiples sheets in there. Each sheet have a name who is saved in dictionary with the controller assigned to it.
Now i would use the controller for save the data in db, but it's designed for used in router ... the controllers all inherited from the same base controller, but a few have a totally different functioning for inserting datas.

```
// in a loop for all sheets
// get the good config then
let controller = require('../../api/' + config.service + '/controller');
controller.create({bodymen: worksheetLine, user, customSchema}); //I would do that, but it's doesn't work

export class BaseController { // a piece of the mother class
  constructor(model) {
    this._model = model;
    this.index = this.index.bind(this);
    this.show = this.show.bind(this);
    this.create = this.create.bind(this);
    this.update = this.update.bind(this);
  }

  create({ bodymen: { body }, user, customSchema}, res, next){
    return this._model.create(Object.assign(body, {company: user.company}, {__user: user}))
      .then((item) => item.view(customSchema))
        .then(success(res, 201))
  }
}
```

I've got the error: TypeError: controller.create is not a function

Thank's you and sorry for my bad English ...

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . You're the only person who can check what `controller` is.